# How do I express JSON-API sparse fieldsets with OpenAPI-3.0

Tags: openapi, json-api

I'm implementing an OpenAPI-3.0 spec for my API, and I plan on using [sparse fieldsets](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets) as a parameter for GETs. The examples for [parameters](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/3.0.0.md#parameterObject) using style=deepObject are a little sparse, so I'm not sure if I've got this exactly right.

```
- in: query
  name: fields
  style: deepObject
  schema:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      type: string
```

Can I combine both the deepObject and additionalProperties options?

I want to support flexible query parameter inputs like this:
`GET /articles?include=author&fields[articles]=title,body&fields[people]=name`
but I don't want to have to spell out every single option for each resource and field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your definition is correct. You might also need to add [`allowReserved: true`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#user-content-parameterallowreserved) so that the comma in `=title,body` is not percent-encoded, and you can add a parameter `example` value for documentation purposes:

```yaml
- in: query
  name: fields
  style: deepObject
  allowReserved: true
  schema:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      type: string
    example:
      articles: title,body
      people: name
```

When using "try it out" in Swagger UI, enter the parameter value in the JSON format like so:

```json
{
  "articles": "title,body",
  "people": "name"
}
```

Swagger UI will serialize the parameter as

```
?fields[articles]=title,body&fields[people]=name
```