# OpenAPI - how to describe query parameters?

Tags: openapi

I'm trying to figure out how to document two of my query parameters in OpenAPI.

**Filtering**

My filtering follows the recommendations of [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering), which takes the form of, for example:

- `?filter[post]=1,2,3`
- `?filter[post]=1,2,3&filter[author]=5`

The `filter` key is an associative array that can contain a set list of resource names in my API. The value assigned to each filter key is either a single id or list of comma separated ids.

**Sorting**

For sorting also follows the [JSON:API recommendation](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sorting), so something like these:

- `?sort=age`
- `?sort=age,-height`

The `sort` query parameter is assigned the value of one sort field or list of comma separated sort fields. Note that the minus sign that prefixes the `height` field indicates a descending sort.

**Question**

How do I represent the my [filtering and sorting in OpenAPI](https://jsonapi.org/format/)?

For example, I'm not sure it's possible for me to specify that the filter key is an associative array, or that it accepts a comma separated list of ids. Almost the same issue for sort: how to represent a comma separated list of sort fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I express JSON-API sparse fieldsets with OpenAPI-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57808396/113116)

Comment: I'm not sure. You're only referring to filtering, right? I'll study that link more. As for the sort, I feel that I need to have `anyOf` along with some `enum` (e.g. [age, -age], [height, -height]) it's clear that sorting can be done by age ASC or age DESC, and/or height ASC or height DESC, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The below approach should help

```yml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: fields
    style: deepObject
    allowReserved: true
    schema:
      type: object
      properties:
        post:
          type: string
        author:
          type: string
  - in: query
    name: sort
    schema:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - age
          - height
```

A part of it is similar to the question that @Helen shared. It'll enable you to use it as in the below image

[image: image1]

And the respective cURL command

```sh
curl -X GET "https://editor.swagger.io/user?filter[post]=1,2&filter[author]=3,4&sort=age&sort=height" -H  "accept: */*"
```

You can also define the `filter` parameter in below way

```yml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: filter
    style: deepObject
    allowReserved: true
    schema:
      type: object
      properties:
        post:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        author:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
```

This will result in the UI being more comprehensive as below

[image: image2]

Then the cURL request looks as below

```sh
curl -X GET "https://editor.swagger.io/user?filter[post]=1&filter[post]=2&filter[author]=3&filter[author]=4&sort=age&sort=height" -H  "accept: */*"
```

And you should probably not need `anyOf` as it's related to inheritance for situations when a method may return an object of the base class or any of its sub-class.

Refer [oneof-anyof-allof-not - OpenAPI Specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) for more info on it.

Comment: Neither filter nor sort comply with the JSON:API specs. Compare the cURL request to the examples I provided. For sort, I feel that I need to express: "anyOf" [name,-name], [age,-age].

Comment: What about the first part of the answer? The one with `curl -X GET "https://editor.swagger.io/user?filter[post]=1,2&filter[author]=3,4&sort=age&sort=height" -H  "accept: */*"` ? Does this also not comply with the JSON:API specs?

Comment: Filter looks right in the cURL example (not sure anymore why I said that was wrong earlier). Sort is definitely wrong. Is it possible to express: "anyOf" [name,-name], [age,-age]?

Comment: If you read the specification, it clearly states the purpose of `anyOf`. It's supposed to be used with Inheritance concepts

Comment: Where does `filter[post]=1,2&filter[author]=3,4` come from in the first example's cURL command? I am trying to convert a filter value of `{ "post": [1,2], "author": [3,4] }` into this with no success. Whatever I try it gets split into `filter[post]=1&filter[post]=2&filter[author]=3&filter[author]=4`.

Comment: Compare the specification that I shared with the ones that you have. If you're using some library to generate the specification (the code-first approach), you might as well need to check and how you can get it done with the library.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a bit old but I'm currently documenting an API whose sort, filter and dynamic relationship includes adheres to the JSON API spec and I just figured out how to properly document the filter query parameter. The below is written in JSON but I hope you'd be able to adapt it to fit your needs if you're writing YAML

```json
{
    "schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "description": "Id of the user",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "referrer_id": {
          "description": "The id of the user that referred the user",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "email_verified": {
          "description": "Whether the user has verified their email address",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "trashed": {
          "description": "Whether the user has been soft deleted",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "with",
            "only"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "in": "query",
    "name": "filter",
    "description": "Really long description.........",
    "style": "deepObject",
    "explode": true,
    "allowReserved": true
  }
```

To document sorting, you can follow the example included [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#query-parameters) which is also written below

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: ids
    description: One or more IDs
    required: true
    schema:
      type: array
      items:
        type: integer
    style: form
    explode: false
    examples:
      oneId:
        summary: Example of a single ID
        value: [5]   # ?ids=5
      multipleIds:
        summary: Example of multiple IDs
        value: [1, 5, 7]   # ?ids=1,5,7
```

Answer (score 0):

For sort its straight forward approach you can find syntax on official guide [Open API Guide](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/)

For sorting:
JSON format

```
"parameters": [{
    "in": "query",
    "name": "sort",
    "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

]

YAML format

```
  parameters:
  - in: query
    name: "sort"
    schema:
    type: array,
    items:
      type: string
```