# API query param definitions in OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi, json-api

We have an API which I am looking to generate an OpenAPI spec for. The API conforms to a JSON:API standard and I have an issue defining the query filter parameters when doing gets on collections.

The basic form is `filter[ attribute ][ operation ]= <value(s)>` as derived from the [spec](https://jsonapi.org/format/#query-parameters-families).

Here is an example of a set of filters applied to a GET in our API.

```
filter[kind][in]=bot,agent&filter[organisation.id][eq]=ee780119-8750-4895-8acbc6-c02fe838924f&page[limit]=10&page[offset]=0&filter[customer.phones][any-like]=%2b88600000000,%2b89666666666
```

Now, the attribute can be any dot path to an attribute in the object and the operation can be any one of a set of supported operations for that attribute (in, eq, any-like, between, etc.).

This gives us the flexibility we want but I struggle to define it in an OpenAPI schema to aid consumers of the API definition.
The pagination parameters are easy to do as I can just define them as follows or use a deep object but this does not extend to the filter[][] case.

```yaml
 - in: query
   name: page[offset]
 - in: query
   name: page[limit]
```

But how can I define filters? Or in general what is the best approach?

Comment: not sure how well this works but I found this example https://github.com/columbia-it/django-jsonapi-training/blob/master/docs/schemas/openapi.yaml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAPI - how to describe query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862351/openapi-how-to-describe-query-parameters)

Comment: Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808396/how-do-i-express-json-api-sparse-fieldsets-with-openapi-3-0